# cython: how to package a python module?

Tags: cython

For example, I have a python module, and the structure is

```
moduleA
  __init__.py
  functionA.py
  moduleB
    __init__.py
    functionB.py
setup.py
```

How can I package the moduleA using cython?

What I have tested:

```
test
  __init__.py
  foo.py
setup.py
```

```
#----------------------------------------------------
## __init__.py
from foo import *

#---------------------------------------------------
## foo.py

def hello():
    print("hello")

# ----------------------------------------------------------
## setup.py
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension('test.foo', ['test/foo.py']),
]

setup(
    name='Test',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    include_dirs=["test"],
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

After `python setup.py build_ext`, a new fold appear:

```
build
  lib.win-amd64-3.7
    test
      foo.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
  temp.win-amd64-3.7
    Release
      test
        foo.cp37-win_amd64.exp
        foo.cp37-win_amd64.lib
        foo.obj
```

Then, `cd ./build/lib.win-amd64-3.7`, and open python interpreter. `import test` is OK, but I can use `hello()` by `test.hello(), test.foo.hello(), test.foo()`.

What's wrong with my process?
The environment is:

```
win 10
python 3.7
cython 0.29.26
```

Update----------------------------------------------------

The above problem can be solved by `python setup.py build_ext --inplace'. Thanks for DavidW's suggestion.

My next question is how to pack a python module?

For example, I have a module as:

```
App
  ModuleA
    __init__.py
    funcA.py
  ModuleB
    __init__.py
    funcB.py
  __init__.py
setup.py
```

I can pack the aoove module by the following `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension('App.ModuleA.funcA', ['App/ModuleA/funcA.py']),
    Extension('App.ModuleB.funcB', ['App/ModuleB/funcB.py']),
]

setup(
    name='App',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    include_dirs=["App"],
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

I manually collect the `ext_modules`. But, if the module has many file, how can I automatically collect the `ext_modules`?

I can only write the following stranger code:

```
name = 'App.'
moduleName = os.listdir('./App')
for mName in moduleName:
  name += mName 
  ...
```

Is there any other elegant methods?

Comment: I think you'd normally use `build_ext --inplace` if you want to build in the same folder. Or you'd do one step further and to `python setup.py install` (which should copy both the extension modules and Python files to a separate location). So what you're doing looks roughly right to me.

Comment: @DavidW, thanks for your kindly suggestion. And how to pack the nested module? I have updated my question. Could you please have a look for the updated part?